# lyx shortcut for superscript and subscript

Tags: lyx, superscripts, keyboard

Instead of using the menu for Insert->Formatting->Superscript or Subscript, I would like to use a keyboard shortcut.

I tried Tools->Preferences->Shortcuts, there are already shortcuts for math-superscript and math-subscript, but they put me in math mode, which is not what I want.

I tried to add a new shortcut, however, I couldn't find the name of the function. I tried "superscript" and "font-superscript" but got an error "Unknown or invalid LyX function name".

How can I find the correct function name?

Comment: See @scottkosty's [answer on how to find the name of a Lyx function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531) by looking at "User commands" under the `View / messages pane`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the status bar (bottom of the LyX window) when you click the appropriate menu item, you'll see the function appear there for a second or two. The two functions you're after are

```
script-insert superscript
script-insert subscript
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> functionality is a bit of a cumbersome way of performing a subscript & superscript addition for normal text in LyX (I am using v2.1); but it does work!

Use the following keys, each individually in the particular order, when you want to add a:

#### SUBscript

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>

#### SUPERscript

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>

Then type the text which you want to have the sub format and return to normal text by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

^   Write superscript

_   Write subscript

Reference: http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/FrequentlyUsedShortcuts#toc3

Comment: these "shortcuts" (actually, basic (la)tex commands) assume math mode, which is not wanted, according to the question.