# Subscript/superscript without using math mode or TeX code box, in LyX?

Tags: lyx, subscripts, superscripts

Is it possible to use subscript and superscript in LyX without entering into math mode or inserting TeX code? For example, can I get H2O to be displayed properly without `\ce{H_{2}O}` or Tex code box with `\textsuperscript{th}` etc.?

Comment: `H\textsubscript{2}O`, but I'm not sure it's easier than `\ce{H2O}`

Comment: @egreg `H\textsubscript{2}O` gives "Undefined control sequence". (and I updated the question in the context of LyX)

Comment: @Sparkler it would be defined with a current version of latex (or use fixltx2e.sty for older releases)

Comment: My answer to this would be "No", and that makes this a feature request on the LyX side, and not (La)TeX-related.

Comment: @Werner I wasn't sure LyX didn't have a wysiwyg wrapper around sup/sub script.

Comment: @Sparkler: A wysiwyg wrapper... like ERT.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What's so onerous about having to type `\ce{H_{2}O}`?

Comment: @Mico the time it takes to write it all.

Comment: @Sparkler `\ce{H2O}` is the correct notation for the `mhchem` package in LaTeX I don't use LyX, but I would assume it's correct there to.

Comment: @PTNobel this is not always comfortable. For example if you have want to bold/italicize/etc. you'd have to treat the text and the math separately. In the posted answer text formatting works the same!

Answer (score 6):

Type 'H', then Insert > Formatting > Subscript, then press the right arrow (this gets you out of the subscript), then type '0'.

You can assign this operation to a key shortcut such as [Ctrl]+[,] using `script-insert subscript` (see also: [lyx shortcut for superscript and subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100962/lyx-shortcut-for-superscript-and-subscript#100967)).