# Shortcut to bring up "Insert" Menu?

Tags: lyx, mac

Is it possible to open the "Insert" menu using a keyboard shortcut for Lyx in Mac OS?
For instance, if I want to insert a new page, I have to click on "Insert", but then I can use my keyboard to navigate to and select "New Page." It would really speed things up if I could just hit some keyboard shortcut and open up the "Insert" menu.

Also, I looked at preferences > editing > shortcuts and could not find a shortcut for inserting cross-references (although I could find ones for labels and citations). Is it possible to create a shortcut to insert a cross-refrence?

Edit: I had an idea: I don't see cross-refrence, or insert-menu in the function list, however I could always enter a function name manually (as shown in the screenshot). Can someone check their shortcuts table and tell me the proper function names? (I assume they're defined, just not in the list).
 [image]

[image]

Comment: Is a in "Insert" underlined? For me "I" is underlined (since "I" is thin, the underline is a little hard to see). This signals that if you do "alt + i" it will open the insert menu.

Comment: I assume you mean the "i" in insert. No. I'll add a screenshot of the menu to the post.

Comment: Regarding finding function names, perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100962 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510 are useful.

Comment: @EvanRosica I wonder if somehow you have something in your user directory that overrides the shortcuts. Try going to Help > About to locate your user directory. THen exit LyX. Then move that user directory somewhere else (do not delete it). Then start LyX and then you will have a fresh user directory.

Comment: @scottkosty I used "cd /" in terminal since the root directory is trivially not part of any other directory. No change as far as I can see (cross references are still gone, still types "i"). As this answer noted https://superuser.com/questions/303525/what-is-the-shortcut-to-access-the-menubar-in-mac-os-x Command + Shift + / brings up the help menu, so theres no reason a shortcut cant bring up the insert menu

Comment: Ahhhhh I just realized I had my keyboard set to Unicode Hex Input, so of course my Alt key wasnt working (in unicode Hex input (you hold alt while entering the 4 numbers)).  I set it back to U.S. and tried your suggestions (about changing directory). In both my user directory and root, alt +i gives ^.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on your OS, but in general: holding the Alt key will show you the shortcut key. (press and hold Alt) - i - o - n - (release Alt) will start a new page. Cross-reference with Alt - i - r.

Comment: I'm on macOS. Neither of these work. In the shortcuts window, I can actually see newpage-insert has no shortcut.

Comment: None of these are chortcuts in ordinary sense and will not be listed in that window. Try all your special keys and see what happens with (special key)+i.

Comment: According to https://superuser.com/questions/303525/what-is-the-shortcut-to-access-the-menubar-in-mac-os-x, this won't work on your OS.

Comment: Thanks for that link.  One of the answers correctly noted that Shift + Command + /  brings up the help menu. Then hitting rightarrow 4 times brings up the inset menu