# ^ started producing literal ^ instead of superscript

Tags: lyx, superscripts, linux, debian, shortcut

I've been using Lyx for years and one of the most basic shortcuts is that ^ doesn't appear literally in math-mode but is displayed as an empty box in the superscript position. A couple of months ago suddenly it started appearing as a literal instead. I have no idea what happened and how to fix it. I use Lyx 2.3.1, i.e. the newest version.

Because it was demanded in a comment: Here a file which is displayed with a literal a^a in Lyx:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula $a^a$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

and here one which correctly displays  $a^a$ :

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula $a^{a}$
\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Both display the correct result when compiled. The only difference between the files is that in the working one, Lyx put braces around the superscript code. Also note that if you have previews enabled this will display correctly as soon as you leave that math mode block.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm not seeking debug help as defined by you. But I can add examples.

Comment: Does the discussion https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100962/15925 help?

Comment: @AndrewSwann No, I already read through that question and answer. They are talking about not-math mode.

Comment: Thank you for the code.  The only difference between the files is braces `{...}` around the superscript.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes, I should have also put that in the question sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was not related to TeX and friends, but due to a keyboard setting.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I was under the impression Lyx was on topic. It's clearly not a TeX or LaTeX problem. There are several questions about Lyx which aren't closed or anything and which have nothing to do with TeX or LaTeX directly

Comment: @Nobody I haven't said that LyX is off-topic. But keyboard settings definitely is off-topic.

Comment: @egreg If Lyx doesn't work with certain keyboard settings then that's related to the keyboard and not to Lyx, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by changing my keyboard layout so the ^ button was no longer a "dead" key, i.e. instead of pressing it twice to get one ^ now I press it once to get a ^ and only then it also works properly in Lyx.